# Want to select all rows except first row of every customer_id

Tags: sql, duplicates, multiple-occurrence

I have the table customer which conatins data of customer in multiple months.

My task is to show the repeated customer with there details in which i need the fetch the rows from second occurrences but the my query is fetching the first occurrence also
[Customer table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSYdD.png)

and i want a query to get this result.
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpnCG.png)

Comment: Please don’t link to images, add all relevant information directly to your question preferably as editable text

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY Id ASC) Sno,* FROM @tbl
) a WHERE a.Sno > 1

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE customer_id IN (
  SELECT customer_id
  FROM table_name
  WHERE customer_id IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY customer_id
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
AND (customer_id, transaction_date) NOT IN (
  SELECT customer_id, MIN(transaction_date)
  FROM table_name
  WHERE customer_id IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY customer_id
)
```